# Transform dataframe with summarizing its column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe, which looks like this:

```
Date                             Price     Type
2018-08-17 10:48:02              120        A
2018-08-17 10:55:02              100        A
2018-08-17 10:57:02              70         B
2018-08-17 10:58:07              69         B
2018-08-20 22:58:13              56         A
2018-08-21 04:19:53              79         A
2018-08-21 04:29:56              40         A
2018-08-21 09:15:07              11         B
2018-08-21 17:07:03              600        A
2018-08-21 17:57:11              225        C
```

I want to transform Date column, so it shows only day and hour and for values in column "Price", they must sum for each hour depending on column Type. So, desired result must look like this:

```
    Date                  Price_sum        Type
2018-08-17 10:00:00         220             A
2018-08-17 10:00:00         139             B
2018-08-20 22:00:00         56              A
2018-08-21 04:00:00         119             A
2018-08-21 09:00:00         11              B
2018-08-21 17:00:00         600             A
2018-08-21 17:00:00         225             C
```

How could i get it? I have no idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `floor_date` from `lubridate` to floor the time at nearest hour and sum those values.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  group_by(Date = floor_date(ymd_hms(Date), 'hour'), Type) %>%
  summarise(Price_sum = sum(Price), 
            n = n())

#  Date                Type  Price_sum     n
#  <dttm>              <chr>     <int> <int>
#1 2018-08-17 10:00:00 A           220     2
#2 2018-08-17 10:00:00 B           139     2
#3 2018-08-20 22:00:00 A            56     1
#4 2018-08-21 04:00:00 A           119     2
#5 2018-08-21 09:00:00 B            11     1
#6 2018-08-21 17:00:00 A           600     1
#7 2018-08-21 17:00:00 C           225     1
```

Comment: Thanks man, i forgot to write, how to add column which counts how many rows there were within each hour and Type

Comment: Updated the answer to include that.

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can try

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>% 
  mutate(Date = ymd_hms(Date),
         hour_only = hour(Date)) %>% 
  group_by(Type, hour_only) %>% 
  mutate(Price2 = sum(Price)) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  arrange(Date) %>% 
  select(Date, Price2, Type)
# Date                Price2 Type 
# <dttm>               <int> <chr>
# 1 2018-08-17 10:48:02    220 A    
# 2 2018-08-17 10:57:02    139 B    
# 3 2018-08-20 22:58:13     56 A    
# 4 2018-08-21 04:19:53    119 A    
# 5 2018-08-21 09:15:07     11 B    
# 6 2018-08-21 17:07:03    600 A    
# 7 2018-08-21 17:57:11    225 C
```